# codeigniter form validation doesn't call callback function

Tags: php, codeigniter

By some reason form validation doesn't call callback function which I set in the rules.

It is rules sets

```
    if( ! empty($_POST))
    {
        ci()->form_validation->set_rules('login', 'Username', 'trim|required');
        ci()->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|callback_check_email');           

        if (ci()->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
        {

        }           

    }
```

and a function

```
public function check_email($str)
{
    ci()->load->model(array('secure_model', 'admin/members_model'));
    $o['username'] =    ci()->input->post('login');
    $o['email'] =       ci()->input->post('email');
    $m = $this->_model->get_row($o);
    if ( ! $m)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_email',  lang('unlock_incorrect_login'));
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

I set `FALSE` twice to see if it call callback function but it doesn't display error message. So I suppose CI doesn't try to call it. What is wrong?

Comment: I see two possibilites:  1) this line: if (ci()->form_validation->run() == TRUE) has little chance of working correctly, as the system defined value of TRUE could be anything.  Much better to to use: if (ci()->form_validation->run() != FALSE).  2) the call back function name is 'check_mail()' not 'callback_check_email()'  I suspect a syntax error in defining the call back function in the set_rules()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `check_email()` function, you're using `$this->form_validation` instead of `ci()->`. I'm not sure why you're using `ci()` instead of the standard CI way of using `$this` but that's the part in your code which seems off compared to the rest.